# How do I view a VNC Session of Ubuntu Server in full screen window?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, vncserver, tightvnc

I have tried multiple attempts to change the size of the screen but all it does is seem to fill the screen with a zoomed in image. When I run eclipse the app window is too small to see any of the code. Any suggestions would be great.

screen shot:

[image]

I can get it to fill the full screen (no black bars) but the remote image is still the same size. I am constantly scrolling back and forth to view the code.  How can I make the visible screen area fill out to the full size of the VNC session window?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You should share some more details or maybe post a screenshot that helps understanding your situation.

Comment: did you try to change the screen resolution in ubuntu?